# Transfer or Stage a Linked Server Database in SQL Server in SSIS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, linked-server

A customer has a SQL 2016 Server on an Azure VM. 
There's a linked server pointing to a MYSQL Database in the US.
They need to transfer ALL data from the Linked Server (MYSQL) to the local SQL Server in Europe to access the data.

I was suggesting using SSIS, but I can't find how to make a connection work using a Linked Server (looks like the "Transfer Database" task doesn't accept it)

Any idea on how to be done? 
As a last resort I will have to write some SQL Script, one table at a time, like :

```
select * into sql_local.dbo.table 1 from openquery ([MYSQL], 'Select * from remote.Table1')
```

but of course I would prefer to have it automated.

EDIT: so far I manged to run a script which drops the DB and recreates it, then a cursor that scrolls the "information_schema.tables" and makes a SELECT INTO on every table.
It works quite well and takes about 7 minutes to finish (198 tables , 400MB total)

```
/**Cursor to scroll ALL tables**/

SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    DECLARE @table_name varchar(255)

/**Reads the list of tables from information_schema.tables**/
DECLARE tables_cursor CURSOR FOR   

select * from openquery ([MYSQL], 'Select TABLE_NAME from information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=''MyDatabase'' ');

OPEN tables_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor   
INTO @table_name 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    PRINT 'Exporting ' +@table_name+ '...' 
    declare @sql varchar(4000)
    SET @sql='select * into MyDatabase_local.dbo.'+@table_name +' from openquery ([MYSQL], ''Select * from MyDatabase.' + @table_name+''')'

    EXEC (@sql)
    FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor   

INTO @table_name 
END   
CLOSE tables_cursor ;  
DEALLOCATE tables_cursor;  
PRINT 'Export completed!'
```

Comment: Why not to connect to MySQL directly from SSIS and just transfer data?

Comment: I know it could work, but I cannot do it, the Company would not allow me, the scenario I have is fixed, I am afraid. 
They only enabled read-only acces thru linked servers, and after many negotiations....

Comment: If a linked server is set up, the data can already be accessed.  Why is there a need to copy it?

Comment: @Antonio You ask for automation but you describe a simplistic task. Is this some type of replication? If you automate this, do you intend to simply pull all the data **every time** without any need to merge changes? Before you decide on a path, you need to understand your goal - and then include that useful information in your question.

Comment: yes, they need to transfer ALL data each time (once a day).

they want to get data locally because the linked server is in Europe but they need a second copy in the US with a replica of the data for reporting and analysis purpose.